# Maximizing saturation while converting CMYK to RGB

Tags: cmyk, rgb, imagemagick

I have many designs prepared for print (CMYK), but now I need to present them on a projector. As projectors go, I know most of them have weak contrast, and many of my colors wouldn't be as accented as I would like them to be.

Therefore, I want to do some batch process on all the vector graphics (PDF) to increase saturation (into RGB color space). What would be the best way to do so?

The graphics share a color scheme, but not exactly identical.

(I'd prefer `imagemagick` solutions if there is one.)

Comment: Assuming you're aware of [modulate](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate) for adjusting saturation... is this specific to wanting to get a better CMYK=>RGB conversion result?

Answer (score 1):

The CMYK gamut is smaller than the RGB gamut and is, more or less, encompassed by RGB. Conversions ought to be nearly seamless most of the time (at least, for the purposes you are shooting for).

Beyond that: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#modulate

> -modulate 100,100,100

Parameters are H,S,L and `100` = "no change"